# BottomNavigationView - How to change the shape of each item's ripple effect

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview, ripple

I'm developing an app that has a `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` every item has a round ripple effect on it. But I want to change the shape of the ripple to square and also I want to add margins on that ripple. I have a custom ripple in my `XML` folder but I would like to know how do I set it on the `BottomNavigationView`

this is my custom ripple

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/red"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

BottomNavigationView

[image: BottomNavigationView]

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me

[At first, is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juMDN.png)

just add this code in XML bottom navigation

```
app:itemBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

[And changed to square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rnmL.png)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is creating a custom ripple like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorLightGray">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorLightGray" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and then in my `BottomNavigationView` adding `app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_nav_bar"` bewate not to set the ripple directly in the background as this does not work

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            style="@style/BottomNavTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_nav_bar"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_home_archive" />
```

The result in my case are squircle shaped ripples that are pleasing to the eye